# Listening to 2 senders on the same USB Port using Docklight

Tags: vbscript, port, serial-communication, usbserial, docklight

I am currently working on a script in docklight v2.0.

**My setup is the following:**

- I have a splitter connected in the USB port of my PC.
- That splitter is connected on a wire on which a communication is made between 2 devices.
- Docklight is connected on the USB port and receives all the information transmited through that wire.
- I have a script on docklight set up to put every byte in a buffer once docklight sniffs them.
- My script is coded using the functions in Docklight and VBScript.

**The problem I have is the following:**

I put all the bytes in the same buffer, that mixes up the messages from both devices and it becomes impossible to analyse them.

**What I need to do:**

I need to know which byte comes from which device, Docklight is already able to do so, but I need to do that in my script so I can put the bytes in 2 different buffers to treat the data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fonction `DL.OnReceive_GetChannel()` solved my problem.